# How to override Laravel 5.8 Attempt method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have been very much wondering how the attempt method works at background in `Laravel`, how it creates user session. My authentication process is much different, I am not using the database to authenticate at all, but instead I am using some data from third party API and then generate user sessions in my application.

During this implementation I do want to use the amazing laravel Auth features.

I know this is doable, may be there is a simple process for this, but I am not understanding the correct one.

Comment: Are you storing any of the user data in your application's database i.e. are when you've got the data from the 3rd party api are you storing it in your application?

Comment: I don't, I don't or will not have any application database at all.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend not trying to use the `attempt` method (or any of the built-in auth logic) and simply store whatever information you want in the session and then create a piece of middleware that checks for the value(s) in the session.